# Printing Auto generated Bar Code Image in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, barcode

I have able create bar code in my php project and now I want to print my barcode so I use javascript but when it comes to print part image is not showing. link to my bar code image is as this

```
http://localhost/Labortory_Management_System/assets/barcode/test_1D.php?text=3921214754
```

How to print thing image?

PS

I use this javascript to print the image

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```